# How does SEO relates to a website's search

Tags: seo, search

I have a website which uses search. I'm curious how do the search results *on my website* get indexed by engines like google. E.g. you can type in google "LinkedIn Apple Inc" or "Facebook Apple Inc" and it will give you a link to the apple's profile on linkedin or facebook website. But there are millions of companies registered on both. How does google know about them? There are no static links for every company, for google to crawl through.

More importantly, what can I do to help google do the same for my website. I want to type into google "nutsdirectory hazelnut" and have google suggest the hazelnut result on my website.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "Linkedin Apple" or "Facebook apple works because Linkedin has static links to those profiles/pages [Facebook Apple](https://www.facebook.com/apple/) | [Linkedin Apple](https://www.linkedin.com/company/apple) | even for smaller companies link | [Linkedin Mounty](https://www.linkedin.com/company/mounty/). So google indexes these links in its directory hence they are visible in the SERPs.

If you want the same for your website, create SEO friendly URLs for your web pages. With proper use of sitemaps and search console, the pages wil be indexed and would be visible on the google SERPs.